# If you Cut and Paste a file to somewhere else, will the entry to the original file remain there?

Tags: data-recovery

So, will the entry remain there, just as if you Shift+Deleted or does it get permanently deleted?

Note that this is not a duplicate of my previous question, I just didn't manage to integrate the two. I consider these two questions separate.

Ext4 and NTFS. The "somewhere else" is in the same filesystem but I'm also curious what happens if I move it to another filesystem, that is move between Ext4 and NTFS back and forth.

Answer (score 2):

In both NTFS and EXT4, files do not get deleted immediately.

Moving them from one location to another does not change the physical location of the file, just the pointer to that file.

As for deletion, while bypassing the recycle bin, the pointer to the file is removed.  This marks the space as free, however the original data of that file remains where it was until it is overwritten.  This is how data recovery tools are able to recover deleted files.  They look at the free space and try to detect if the data there is a file.

Comment: So this is just as if I deleted them with Shift+Delete?

Comment: @shadowwar yes. Al that does is bypass the recycle bin.

Comment: This is not entirely related, so how come the file does not occupy space, if it is deleted and it shows as "free space"?

Comment: @shadowwar When you delete a file in the OS the data is still physically on the disk (until overwritten by something else). Deleting merely removes the link to the file from the Master File Table. So from the perspective of the OS the file no longer exists (as it is not referenced in the MFT) and is free space to be used for other files. To actually *permanently* delete a file you'd need to use some tool which writes over all free space on the disk, thus actually erasing the physical data from the disk.

Comment: "the pointer to the file is removed" For NTFS, this is true for the index record (usually) but not for the MFT entry. @Chro "removes the link to the file from the Master File Table" if by "the link" you mean the MFT entry, this is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

## This answer applies to NTFS

> will the entry to the original file remain there?

Yes. The **MFT entry** of the file (there is no "original" and no "copy") stays there. The OS only needs to:

- update the parent id in the MFT entry
- remove the element from the children of the old parent directory
- add the element to the children of the new parent directory

Each MFT entry of a directory has a `$INDEX_ROOT` attribute which lists a few children, while the rest are saved somewhere else (this somewhere being located by having one or more `$INDEX_ALLOCATION` attributes).

When the OS moves a file inside the same file system, these "lists of children" (although technically they are [B+ trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree)) are updated.

Note that **it might be possible to carve remnant entries** from the slack space of index records.

> I'm also curious what happens if I move it to another filesystem

Moving a file to a different file system is treated as:

- a copy to the new file system
- an instant deletion of the file from the original file system

In this case the MFT entry also remains, but it is marked as deleted. It can be overwritten when new files are created and additional MFT entries are needed.